# How to populate userdata in jqGrid footer from server side

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am displaying data in jqGrid where i need to show the userdata in footer of jqgrid. I am using Servlet as server side and my datatype is json. Manually i am formatting data as JSON type.

Here is my JSON data format:

```json
{"page":"1",
"total":8,
"records":375,
"userdata":{'totalcdrcost':'302.92'},
"rows": [
{"id":"1","cell":[1,"2011-09-16","04:36:02","9035020090","00618956189189","00","13","00:01:09","ISD","9.6","Mumbai"]},
{"id":"2","cell":[2,"2011-09-16","04:35:14","9742796383","h","00","11","00:01:54","INCOMING","0","Mumbai"]},
```

Now i want to show this `userdata` on footer row for that i enabled footer row also.here is my footer code..

```
footerrow : true, userDataOnFooter : true
```

But no data is displayed in the jqGrid... I don't know is this because JSON data format is not correct or something else.

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part of JSON response is incorrect:

```
"userdata":{'totalcdrcost':'302.92'}
```

It should be something like

```
"userdata":{"totalcdrcost":"302.92"}
```

to be correct JSON. If you want to use `footerrow : true, userDataOnFooter : true` options then the data from `userdata` part will be displayed in the footer it there are exist the column `"totalcdrcost"` in the grid (like `name` property in `colModel`).

Comment: Thanks a lot oleg you are life saviour

Comment: @vikas: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you again.